# Updating to Meteor 0.9.1 woes (broke the app big time)

Tags: meteor

I’ve had some serious problems after updating meteor to 0.9.1.

Here are some example errors from the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function -- in dynamic_template.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘prototype’ of undefined -- in helpers.js
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function -- in router.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘RouteController’ of undefined -- in iron-router-progress.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘RouteController’ of undefined -- in global-imports.js
```

And dozens of: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined` -- in client view js files, both the hard copies that I have created and the apparently ephemeral files that meteor apparently creates on the fly.

And fewer dozens of: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined` -- in the same kind of files.

And one: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Spacebars is not defined` -- in login_buttons_dialogs.html

And about 10 sockjs errors on `GET — net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I can’t help thinking that either something very basic was not accomplished during the update procedure or there are some very basic and widespread changes that need to be made in my code in order for it to run 0.9.1.

I’m building a app that is an extension and morph of the microscope app.  It's not rocket science at this point.  It was working last night before the update.  It was 0.9.0.1 before the update.

All help and insight is appreciated.

Comment: You could try rebuilding your app from scratch if that's not too much of an issue : `meteor create test && cd test` then copy over all of your app source code, then add the packages you are using one by one and see how it goes.

Comment: try running 'Meteor bundle" with package numbers, might solve it.
also, if your using iron-router, try removing it and adding it from "iron:router".

Comment: Would you please list the packages you're using in your app? There are several packages that broke with the 0.9.1 upgrade. This one got me: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/53

Comment: Same problem here. You can revert with `meteor update --release 0.9.0.1`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the guidance.  All seems to be well now.  This is what I did:

I created a new meteor app, removed 2 default packages, then added:
bootstrap
iron:router
mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-dropdown
accounts-password
mrt:iron-router-progress
sacha:spin

Then I copied my files from the broken app to the new app and viola', everything worked.

I see that the directory structure and its naming conventions have changed, colons in place of dashes in a few spaces and the direcory or namespace prefixes such as mrt, iron, and sacha.

Here's an unexpected thing.  I previously had a folder called packages in which there was a folder for each package containing all its files.  Now that folder is empty, but everything is still working.  I'm clearly under informed about a few things.

Again, thanks for the guidance.  Even though this was a pain, I see that the resulting changes needed to happen.

Best, Alex

Answer (score 1):

Many packages are breaking on Meteor@0.9.1, I suggest you create a new Meteor app like so:

```
$ meteor create --release 0.9.0 app
$ cd app
$ meteor remove insecure
$ meteor remove autopublish
```

and then add all the packages you need with `meteor add packagename` and copy over all the files from your app.

Stick with Meteor@0.9.0 until you know you can safely upgrade!